# Integer division in Dhall

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, division, integer-division, dhall

I would like to compute the quotient of two `Natural`s. The requirement I need to fulfill is that I have a few configuration items that must be dynamically defined as shares of another (i.e. one container has `X` memory, two configuration keys for the process in that container are defined as `X / Y` and `X / Z`).

My first idea was to use recursion, but this approach didn't work:

```
let quotient =
  \(n: Natural) ->
  \(m: Natural) ->
    if lessThan n m then 0
    else 1 + quotient (Natural/subtract m n) m
```

In particular, Dhall complains that `quotient` has not been defined yet when I try to call it. Given Dhall's total functional paradigm (and my unfamiliarity with it) this seems reasonable. I assume there may be some way of doing it, but unfortunately I couldn't get to it.

I did another attempt using `Natural/fold` that works, but I'm not sure whether this makes sense.

```
let quotient =
      λ(n : Natural) →
      λ(m : Natural) →
        let div =
              λ(n : Natural) →
              λ(m : Natural) →
                let Div = { q : Natural, r : Natural }

                in  Natural/fold
                      n
                      Div
                      ( λ(d : Div) →
                          if    Natural/isZero m
                          then  d
                          else  if lessThan d.r m
                          then  d
                          else  { q = d.q + 1, r = Natural/subtract m d.r }
                      )
                      { q = 0, r = n }

        in  (div n m).q
```

This passes all the following assertions.

```
let example1 = assert : quotient 1 1 ≡ 1
let example2 = assert : quotient 2 2 ≡ 1
let example3 = assert : quotient 3 1 ≡ 3
let example4 = assert : quotient 3 2 ≡ 1
let example5 = assert : quotient 9 4 ≡ 2
let example6 = assert : quotient 4 5 ≡ 0
let example7 = assert : quotient 0 1 ≡ 0
let example8 = assert : quotient 0 2 ≡ 0
let example9 = assert : quotient 1 0 ≡ 0
let example9 = assert : quotient 0 0 ≡ 0
let example9 = assert : quotient 2 0 ≡ 0
```

Returning `0` when dividing by `0` is fine in my case.

Is there a more idiomatic way of achieving this? I looked for a ready-made integer division function in the `Prelude` but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is not a simpler way to implement `Natural` division besides what you have already written, but there may be a more efficient approach.  Another approach that would give logarithmic time complexity but with a significantly more complex implementation is "guess and check", where you do a binary search around around the desired number to find the largest number `x` such that `x * m = n`.

I wouldn't really recommend that, though and I think probably a better way is to see if there is a sensible built-in to add to the language that could power integer division efficiently.  Ideally such a built-in would be well-defined for all inputs, so adding integer division directly would probably not work (since `x / 0` is not well-defined).  However (I'm spitballing here), perhaps a built-in like `Natural/safeDivide x y == x / (y + 1)` could work, and then users could define their own wrappers around that if they want to permit division by `0`.  Probably the best place to solicit ideas for what the built-in would look like is the Discourse forum:

https://discourse.dhall-lang.org/

Comment: Hm, if `Natural/subtract 3 1 === 0`, then why shouldn't `Natural/divide x 0 === 0`?

Comment: I just tried to divide 2^30 by 6 with the above implementation and obviously ran out of memory. So I'm curious: How would you implement the binary search? Don't you need division by 2 and a logarithm for that (I thought I could approximate the logarithm by Natural/show + string length,

Answer (score 2):

TL;WR Edit:

```
let Natural/div = λ(n : Natural) → λ(m : Natural) → 
    let div = https://github.com/jcaesar/dhall-div/releases/download/1/quotient.dhall sha256:d6a994f4b431081e877a0beac02f5dcc98f3ea5b027986114487578056cb3db9
    in (div n m).q
```

---

Gabriel Gonzalez had me well nerd-sniped with his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64149161/401059) mentioning binary search. For a while, I was running in circles, trying whether the division by two necessary for the search couldn't be implemented by converting numbers to `List Bool` (well, it can, with the same problem as below), then I noticed that you can just implement long division:

```
let Natural/le = λ(a : Natural) → λ(b : Natural) → Natural/isZero (Natural/subtract b a)
let Natural/equals = λ(a : Natural) → λ(b : Natural) → Natural/le a b && Natural/le b a
  
let bits =    
      λ(bits : Natural) →
        Natural/fold
          bits          
          (List Natural)
          ( λ(l : List Natural) →
                l
              # [ merge
                    { Some = λ(i : Natural) → i * 2, None = 1 }
                    (List/last Natural l)
                ] 
          )
          ([] : List Natural)

in  λ(w : Natural) →
      let bits = bits w
      in  λ(n : Natural) →
          λ(m : Natural) → 
            let T = { r : Natural, q : Natural } : Type
            let div =
                  List/fold
                    Natural
                    bits
                    T 
                    ( λ(bit : Natural) →
                      λ(t : T) →
                        let m = m * bit
                        in  if    Natural/le m t.r
                            then  { r = Natural/subtract m t.r, q = t.q + bit }
                            else  t 
                    )               
                    { r = n, q = 0 }
            in  if Natural/equals m 0 then 0 else div.q
```

The only catch is that since there's no logarithm, you can't do the left-alignment in the tableau for long division, i.e. you don't know how the position of the MSB in `n` or how long `subs` has to be.

The theorist in me is sad because I just reduced division to (a coarse approximation of) logarithm, but the practitioner says "You're happy with u64 all the time, shut up."

---

[Edit] After a bit of thinking, I still can't compute the logarithm efficiently and for all inputs (I don't think that's possible). But I can find the next power of two from the logarithm for numbers up to a fixed large limit (2^2^23 or 42 × 10^2525221, but see below). It is possible to modify the above function (let's call it `quotient`) the following way:

```
let Natural/less =
      λ(a : Natural) → 
      λ(b : Natural) →
        if Natural/isZero (Natural/subtract a b) then False else True

let max = 23

let powpowT = { l : Natural, n : Natural }
      
let powpow =
      Natural/fold
        max
        (List powpowT)
        ( λ(ts : List powpowT) →
            merge 
              { Some = 
                  λ(t : powpowT) → [ { l = t.l + t.l, n = t.n * t.n } ] # ts
              , None = [ { l = 1, n = 2 } ]
              }
              (List/head powpowT ts)
        )
        ([] : List powpowT)

let powpow = List/reverse powpowT powpow
      
let bitapprox =
      λ(n : Natural) →
        List/fold
          powpowT 
          powpow
          Natural 
          ( λ(e : powpowT) →
            λ(l : Natural) →
              if Natural/less n e.n then e.l else l
          )
          0

in  λ(n : Natural) → λ(m : Natural) → quotient (bitapprox n) n m
```

This gives an acceptably efficient implementation of quotient, with a long division tableau that's maximally twice as large as necessary. On my desktop (62GB) m, I can compute e.g. 2^(2^18) / 7 in 11 seconds, but run out of memory for larger numbers.

Anyway, if you have beef with numbers that large, you're using the wrong language.